# Как отключить автоматическое создание тегов в PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Как отключить это поведение в PhpStorm:
пишу любое слово, нажимаю пробел, чтобы дальше писать слова, но PhpStorm это слово делает его тегом.
Вот пример того, что получается

```
<div class="title"><слово></слово></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

выбрать место Space -> Custom..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]